# Shifting by 1 an array of C structures

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, shift

I have an array of structures that I am trying to shift left by 1 array node.  The total size of the array is huge (about 3 gigabytes), so even though I know the exact size of array I need, it is too big to declare on the stack (even though I have 16 gig of ram and am writing a 64bit program), thus complicating things by forcing me to do dynamic memory alloc:

```
struct s_ptx
{
    short       streamIndex;
    double      raw;
    char        rawDx;

}  *Ptx[100];

void allocateMemory(void)
{
    ptxTotal = 300;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)   
        Ptx[i] = (struct s_ptx*) calloc( ptxTotal, sizeof(struct s_ptx));
}

void shiftDataStructures(void)
{
    for (int j = 100 - 1; j > 0; --j) 
        Ptx[j] = Ptx[j - 1];
}
```

But I get wrong results, because the shiftDataStructures function is not working.  Any ideas of how I need to rewrite this.

Comment: What do you want to do with Ptx[0] ?  free() it or rotate it to Ptx[99] ? And in case of the former, what do you want to do with Ptx[99] ?

Comment: Please provide more details on your program.

Comment: The objective is to shift the array, letting the last one in node [99] fall off.  I then fill [0] with new values.

Comment: Antti: you wrote: "You are not shifting structs, only pointers."  Are you saying that all I need to do is change it to: *Ptx[j] = *Ptx[j - 1] ?

Comment: then it would copy the first of your 300 structures in each spot. I wonder, why do you necessarily want to copy 3G of data all the time? There must be a bad mistake in your design ;)

Comment: If what you are trying got achieve is have an array with the 100 most recent occurrences of a structure, you might consider keeping a rotating index rather than move all your data at each time.

Comment: Hope you're aware you're shifting the pointers one right, not one left. E.g. if you had pointers (0, 1, 2, 3) your loop will produce (0, 0, 1, 2). To shift one left: for (int i = 0; i < 100 - 1; i++) { Ptx[i] = Ptx[i + 1]; }. This will map (0, 1, 2, 3) to (1, 2, 3, 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not shifting structs, only pointers. I wonder what you really are thinking you are achieving here?

Also, why do you need to shift array indexes at all, why not use, say, linked list or a ring buffer. As to what the error itself would be, I have no clue because you provide insufficient data; your loop is running in correct direction as not to overwrite the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping the data inside the structures of instead of shifting the pointers. The resultant will result in a circular array where Ptx[99] will be circulated to Ptx[0].

Sample code:

```
 // Change codes in the following line
 for (int j = 100 - 1; j > 0; --j)
      //Ptx[j] = Ptx[j - 1];
        swap(Ptx[j], Ptx[j - 1]);
```